# Who/what is this action figure in Abby's lab?

Tags: props, ncis

I've been binge-watching season 13 of NCIS and I've repeated seen an action figure from a reverse angle beside (one of) her computer monitor(s). In episode S13E23 there is finally a front view of the toy/doll/whatever.

[image]

Given that Abbs has a taste for non-conformist appetites, can you identify this plastic avatar?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## Bleeding Edge Goths, by Varner Studios

After a hint from the [Wikipedia page for Abby's character](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abby_Sciuto#Characterization): that is a [Bleeding Edge Goths doll, by Varner Studios](http://www.varnerstudios.com/bleeding_edge_goths), from the "Series 2 Exclusives" set.

[image]